# Laravel how to save HTML to database and then retrieve it

Tags: html, database, laravel

This question was already asked, however, I still didn't get anything working properly.

I am trying to create a functionality in my Admin Panel on my Laravel App that allow user to paste ad codes that then will be rendered in specific parts of the laravel app.

I already have my view:

```
<form action="{{ route('update.ads', $ads->id) }}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-12" >Ad1 (Interstitial or popup on Homepage)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="ad1" id="ad1" class="form-control" value="{{ $ads->ad1 }}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-12" >Ad2 (Video Page - Banner Desktop)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="ad2" id="ad2" class="form-control" value="{{ $ads->ad2 }}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-12" >Ad3 (Video Page - Banner Mobile)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="ad3" id="ad3" class="form-control" value="{{ $ads->ad3 }}">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Update" />
            </div>

        </div>
</form>
```

I have my controller:

```
public function updateAds($id, Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'ad1',
        'ad2',
        'ad3'
    ]);


    $adsData = $request->only(["ad1","ad2","ad3"]);

    $adsData['ad1'] = htmlentities($adsData['ad1']);
    $adsData['ad2'] = htmlentities($adsData['ad2']);
    $adsData['ad3'] = htmlentities($adsData['ad3']);

    Ad::find($id)->update($adsData);

    Session::flash('success_msg', 'Ads updated successfully!');

    return redirect()->route('admin.ads');
}
```

Data is saved, but then when i try to retrieve it on my pages, no matter what code i write, the content will always be text. It is never rendered as code.

Here is what i have tried in terms of output:

```
{{ addslashes(htmlspecialchars_decode($ads->ad1)) }}

{{ htmlspecialchars_decode($ads->ad1) }}
```

Thank you all for your help!
Regards,
Tiago

Comment: replace `{{ }}` with `{!!  !!}`. **Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. Always use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.** see [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: What you suggested made it work!! Post an answer instead of a comment in order for me to vote for it ! thanks!!!

Comment: Don't ignore the warning. As you are trying to echoing content that is supplied by user there is a big security issue. If a user saves the code as ``env('DB_PASSWORD')` it will show your application's db password when displaying with `{!!  !!}`. Or they might able to execute sql queries.

Comment: I undertsand your concern, but in this case, the only user that will access the form to add the codes is the admin.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `{{ }}` is the "safe" blade echo; it actually re-encodes things with htmlspecialchars automatically before outputting the data.

Try `{!! html_entity_decode($ads->ad1) !!}` or something similar. I'm not sure how it's getting stored, so you might have to do different decoding, but the key thing here is to use `{!! !!}`, which displays the raw, unescaped data.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score -1):

The {{ }} is the "          " blade echo; it actually re-encodes things with htmlspecialchars automatically before outputting the data.

Comment: this is not an answer you should better to post that in comment